# World map that zooms into country using HTML5

Tags: javascript, canvas, dictionary, svg, geocoding

I have been looking at RaphaelJS, D3, and other "mapping" tools (jvectormap, etc) but I could not find any example of a world map that will zoom into a country on mouse click.  I want to initially see a world map and then, when you click on a country it will zoom in and just show that country (with the world not showing and you can zoom out to the world at any point).  Here is a bad example:

http://htmlpreview.github.com/?https://raw.github.com/escobar5/raphael-pan-zoom/master/examples/complete-map/index.html

Can you point me to an example, preferably in D3, protovis, Raphael, or another popular SVG/CANVAS type library.  I will be adding lots of data points (based on geo coords) to these maps.

The closest example to what I need is the d3 map on http://theartofasking.com but I was looking for more examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the two examples under [D3.js World Map that Zooms into each Country on Click](http://techslides.com/d3-world-maps-tooltips-zooming-and-queue/).  You should be able to expand on that and build what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I built something similar a little while ago simply with SVG and jQuery. I'm animating the entire map's width and height and moving it's position to fake the effect of zooming. It does the job, works across all browsers and doesn't rely on learning a new Library.

https://igr-inc.com/iGR_Global_Statistics_Services/

This example zooms in on continents but you can go into as much details as possible. Have a look at the source, hopefully it's quite self explanatory but do shout if you have and queries.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I see what you did but it does not fit my use case.  I need to load individual countries separately from the world because of the data points (not zoom into the world view).  Consider plotting all cities on a world map, it would not look good and load slow.  But, I can show just the capitols on the world map and when someone clicks on a country, I can then load all the cities od that country.

Comment: No worries. There's no reason why you couldn't load each country individually. It is difficult when dealing with large amounts of SVG data, as loading time will be slow. If your map doesn't need too much detail then you could just use png's. If you used just 1 colour the file size would be tiny!

Answer (score 0):

You can see another example of a JavaScript map with zoom in/out

http://www.fla-shop.com/products/html5/world/zoom-world-map/

It uses RaphaelJS.

Answer (score 0):

This map may do what you want with d3, zooming into each country and breaking up each country into first level admin districts (counties / states etc). For the US, which has huge states, it goes one level further and breaks each state into counties.

https://github.com/crittercism/critter-world-map